# Bad results from DBN in Deep Learning Toolbox

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I want to run [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38310-deep-learning-toolbox). When I use `mnist_uint8` data, I can run this code well. But if I run one model (like `DBN.m`) using my own data, this code:

```
[er, bad] = nntest(nn, test_x, test_y);
```

will run nothing, the `er` is zero. why this happened? The input size of my training data is 320*200 and the output is 320*1.

EDIT: Added Code and data files

```
load dataX 
load dataY 
load pdataX 
load pdataY
train_x=dataX/100
test_x=pdataX/100
pdataY(find(pdataY(:,:)<=20))=0;
pdataY(find(pdataY(:,:)>20))=1;
dataY(find(dataY(:,:)<=20))=0;
dataY(find(dataY(:,:)>20))=1;
train_y=dataY
test_y=pdataY
rand('state',0); 
dbn.sizes = [100 40];

%train a 100-40 hidden unit DBN 
opts.numepochs = 1;
opts.batchsize = 40;
opts.momentum = 0;
opts.alpha = 1;
dbn = dbnsetup(dbn, train_x, opts);
dbn = dbntrain(dbn, train_x, opts);

%unfold dbn to nn nn = dbnunfoldtonn(dbn, 1);
nn.activation_function = 'sigm';
%train nn opts.numepochs = 1;
opts.batchsize = 40;
nn = nntrain(nn, train_x, train_y, opts);
[er, bad] = nntest(nn, test_x, test_y);
```

Here is the data

https://mega.co.nz/#!9V5wmKYK!q3nAvrzKZCT_Q3Ae-DDNAGDnV57b6Pzq6gtf01w0lD8

Comment: I think without providing more information about which example you want to run and showing some code, people can not help you.

Comment: this is my data:https://mega.co.nz/#!9V5wmKYK!q3nAvrzKZCT_Q3Ae-DDNAGDnV57b6Pzq6gtf01w0lD8  dataX and dataY are training data , pdataX and pdataY are test data.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but did you train your neural network first? Is it multiclass or binary classification? There is a list of examples that has helped me several times: https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox

Comment: You should also specify the architecture of your NN and the size of your datasets, maybe it's overfitting.

Comment: https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox  I use the code of README.md. this is my data   https://mega.co.nz/#!9V5wmKYK!q3nAvrzKZCT_Q3Ae-DDNAGDnV57b6Pzq6gtf01w0lD8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After much discussion (see comments), the issue was that the targets(y) need to be trained and tested using the one-of-N encoding format. For example [1 0] for class 1 and [0 1] for class 2. The modified code yields a base error rate of 0.2125. Further tuning and architecture change should yield better results.

```
clear all

load dataX 
load dataY 
load pdataX 
load pdataY
train_x=dataX/100;
test_x=pdataX/100;
pdataY(find(pdataY(:,:)<=20))=0;
pdataY(find(pdataY(:,:)>20))=1;
dataY(find(dataY(:,:)<=20))=0;
dataY(find(dataY(:,:)>20))=1;
train_y=dataY
test_y=pdataY

% Add dimension for one-of-N encoding
train_y(:,2) = 1-train_y(:,1);
test_y(:,2) = 1-test_y(:,1);

rand('state',0)
dbn.sizes = [100 40];

%train a 100-40 hidden unit DBN
opts.numepochs = 2;
opts.batchsize = 40;
opts.momentum = 0;
opts.alpha = 1;
dbn = dbnsetup(dbn, train_x, opts);
dbn = dbntrain(dbn, train_x, opts);

%unfold dbn to nn
nn = dbnunfoldtonn(dbn, 2);
nn.activation_function = 'sigm';

%train nn
opts.numepochs = 100;
opts.batchsize = 40;
nn = nntrain(nn, train_x, train_y, opts);
[er, bad] = nntest(nn, test_x, test_y);
```

Original Answer:

I'm assuming your training data is 200 features and 320 training examples. Assuming you trained it properly, then you probably need to perform feature reduction. I know it is popular for ML algorithms running on the MNIST dataset to preprocess it using Principal Component Analysis (see Matlab function [pca](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html)()) to truncate some of the features. Please post more code for us to actually see the problem.